# TaskFactory inner task never get executed and always in WaitingForActivation status

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task, taskfactory

I am using the TaskFactory to start new task using following code.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Do API Call
        var saveResponse = doAPICall();
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}).Unwrap();

task.Wait();
```

The code for doAPICall() is like below which is calling an external API which returns the Task.

```
private string doAPICall()
{
    Task<string> response = client.FindBags(request);
    response.Wait(60000);

    if (response.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
        return response.Result;
    }
}
```

The issue occurs in doAPICall() function that Task 'response' status never change to RanToCompletion and it is always in WaitingForActivation status. I already tried to increase the wait timeout but still no luck. I am using the TaskFactory instead of Task because of in future I want to create custom TaskFactory for more control over scheduler and concurrency.

Is that something I am missing in my code that inner task never get executed?

**Edit**
I modified the code of calling the doAPICall() according to comment of removing unnecessary thread but still no luck. :-(

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Do API Call
        var saveResponse = doAPICall();
});

task.Wait();
```

Comment: Why all this extra Task stuff, I'm seriously asking because you're using more threads then are necessary (more than 1 is unnecessary).  If your API call isn't async by default then the correct way to do this is to use a [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) and not spinning up threads.

Comment: My external API call is a async function which returns the Task.

Comment: Are you trying to call Async code from Sync code?

Comment: doAPICall() function call to external API which is async call while doAPICall is called from Task.Run

Comment: client.FindBags(request) is returns Task and Findbags is async function.

Answer (score 3):

You're currently using sync-over-fake-async-over-fake-async-over-sync-over-async. That is seriously messed up.

Follow these guidelines:

1. Don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Ever. `I am using the TaskFactory instead of Task because of in future I want to create custom TaskFactory for more control over scheduler and concurrency.` Custom task schedulers don't work well with asynchronous code. You'll probably have to adopt more async-friendly solutions for scheduling/concurrency. More info [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).
2. Don't block on asynchronous code. I see two `Wait` calls and a `Result`, both of which are serious red flags. More info [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).
3. Don't use `Task.Status` in production code. It's OK for debugging, but you shouldn't ever have to use it for actual logic. There is always a better solution. More info [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html).
4. Only use `Task.Run` from the UI layer, not nested within helper/library code. In other words, use it to *call* methods, not *implement* methods. More info [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

Working from the innermost method out:

```
private async Task<string> doAPICallAsync()
{
  Task<string> responseTask = client.FindBags(request);
  // Note: it would be far better to use a cancellation token here instead of a "timed wait".
  Task timeoutTask = Task.Delay(60000);
  Task completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(responseTask, timeoutTask);
  if (completedTask == responseTask)
    return await completedTask;
}
```

and your calling code becomes:

```
var saveResponse = await doAPICallAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping an async call in a sync call and then in two async calls. That is way to much, just use one async call and you will be fine.

```
private Task<string> doAPICallAsync()
{
    return client.FindBags(request);
}
```

If you need to do some work after `client.FindBags(request)` use this version:

```
private async Task<string> doAPICallAsync()
{
    var result = await client.FindBags(request);
    var someNewResult = //do something with result
    return someNewResult;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var result = await doAPICallAsync();
```

If you really need a sync version

```
private string doAPICall()
{
    return client.FindBags(request).Result;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var result = doAPICall();
```

If you can, don't forget to add `ConfigureAwait(false)` after every await.

Comment: Thanks wertzui but I need to lot of string operation in doAPICall() function once the result is arrived. So I can use your sync version and call doAPICall() in Task.Factory.StartNew. 

I tried the same but client.FindBags(request).Result will result into the default timeout and Task was cancelled exception is thrown.

Comment: I added a version that you can use to do some work inside of `doAPICallAsync()` after `client.FindBags(request)`